# Can I simply add affine or perspective (homography) matrices of transformation?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, affinetransform, homography

As known, in OpenCV I can get affine or perspective transformation between 2 images:

- **M** - [affine transformation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html) - by using `estimateRigidTransform()`
- **H** - [perspective (homography) transformation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher) - by using `FeatureDetector` (*SIFT, SURF, BRISK, FREAK, ...*), then `FlannBasedMatcher` and `findHomography()`

Then I can do:

- affine transformation - by using `warpAffine(img_src, img_dst, M)`
- perspective transformation - by using `warpPerspective(img_src, img_dst, H)`

But if I have 3 or more images, and I already found:

- affine: M1 (img1 -> img2), M2 (img2 -> img3)
- perspective: H1 (img1 -> img2), H2 (img2 -> img3)

then can I get matix of transformation (**img1 -> img3**) by simply add two matrix?

- of an affine transform: `M3 = M1 + M2;`
- of an perspective  transform: `H3 = H1 + H2;`

Or which of functions should I use for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you need to **multiply** the matrices to get the cascaded effect.  I won't go into the math, but applying a transformation to coordinates is a matter of performing a matrix multiplication.  If you are however curious as to know why that is, I refer you to this [good Wikipedia article on cascading matrix transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Composing_and_inverting_transformations).  Given a coordinate `X` and a transformation matrix `M`, you get the output coordinate `Y` by:

```
Y = M*X
```

Here I use `*` to refer to **matrix** multiplication as opposed to element-wise multiplication.  What you have is a pair of transformation matrices which go from `img1` to `img2` then `img2` to `img3`.  You'll need to do the operation twice.  So to go from `img1` to `img2` where `X` belongs to the coordinate space of `img1`, we have (assuming we're using the affine matrices):

```
Y1 = M1*X
```

Next, to go from `img2` to `img3`, we have:

```
Y2 = M2*Y1 --> Y2 = M2*M1*X --> Y2 = M3*X --> M3 = M2*M1
```

Therefore, to get the desired chain effect, you need to create a new matrix such that `M2` is multiplied by `M1`.  Same as `H2` and `H1`.

So define a new matrix such that:

```
cv::Mat M3 = M2*M1;
```

Similarly for your projective matrices, you can do:

```
cv::Mat H3 = H2*H1;
```

However, `estimateRigidTransform` (the output is `M` in your case) gives you a `2 x 3` matrix.  One trick is to augment this matrix so that it becomes 3 x 3 where we add an additional row where it is all 0 **except** for the last element, which is set to 1.  Therefore, you would have the last row such that it becomes `[0 0 1]`.  You would do this for both matrices, multiply them, then extract just the first two rows into a new matrix to pipe into `warpAffine`.  Therefore, do something like this:

```
// Create padded matrix for M1
cv::Mat M1new = cv::Mat(3,3,M1.type());
M1new.at<double>(0,0) = M1.at<double>(0,0);
M1new.at<double>(0,1) = M1.at<double>(0,1);
M1new.at<double>(0,2) = M1.at<double>(0,2);

M1new.at<double>(1,0) = M1.at<double>(1,0);
M1new.at<double>(1,1) = M1.at<double>(1,1);
M1new.at<double>(1,2) = M1.at<double>(1,2);

M1new.at<double>(2,0) = 0.0;
M1new.at<double>(2,1) = 0.0;
M1new.at<double>(2,2) = 1.0;

// Create padded matrix for M2
cv::Mat M2new = cv::Mat(3,3,M2.type());
M2new.at<double>(0,0) = M2.at<double>(0,0);
M2new.at<double>(0,1) = M2.at<double>(0,1);
M2new.at<double>(0,2) = M2.at<double>(0,2);

M2new.at<double>(1,0) = M2.at<double>(1,0);
M2new.at<double>(1,1) = M2.at<double>(1,1);
M2new.at<double>(1,2) = M2.at<double>(1,2);

M2new.at<double>(2,0) = 0.0;
M2new.at<double>(2,1) = 0.0;
M2new.at<double>(2,2) = 1.0;

// Multiply the two matrices together
cv::Mat M3temp = M2new*M1new;

// Extract out relevant rows and place into M3
cv::Mat M3 = cv::Mat(2, 3, M3temp.type());
M3.at<double>(0,0) = M3temp.at<double>(0,0);
M3.at<double>(0,1) = M3temp.at<double>(0,1);
M3.at<double>(0,2) = M3temp.at<double>(0,2);

M3.at<double>(1,0) = M3temp.at<double>(1,0);
M3.at<double>(1,1) = M3temp.at<double>(1,1);
M3.at<double>(1,2) = M3temp.at<double>(1,2);
```

When dealing with `cv::Mat` and the `*` operator, [it is overloaded to specifically perform matrix multiplication](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions).

You can then use `M3` and `H3` into `warpAffine` and `warpPerspective` respectively.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! But matrix multiplication can be done only if number of columns in 1-st matrix equal to the number of rows in 2-nd matrix. **H - perspective (homography) is a 3x3 matrix**, and **I can do: `H3 = H1*H2;`**. But **affine matrix is a 2x3** and I can't simply multiplicy two affine matricies, **I can't do: `M3 = M1*M2;`**. How can I do this for the Affine Transformation - M?

Comment: `estimateRigidTransform();` gives me 2x3 matrix, `and estimateAffine3D();` gives me 3x4 matrix.

Comment: @Alex - I've added information to help you with `estimateRigidTransform`.  My apologies for not seeing that earlier.  However, `estimateAffine3D` deals with the transformation between one 3D point cloud to another.  You can't use that to warp images because images are inherently a 2D coordinate space.

Comment: @Alex - Make sure you get the order right.  It's `H2*H1` and `M2*M1`.

Comment: A perspective transformation is non-linear even though it can be written in matrix form, since the resulted vector needs to be divided by a factor determined by the original vector. Are you sure H3=H1*H2 is valid in this case?

An inverse homography (i.e. getting from img1's to img2's perspective when H is getting from img2's to img1's perspective) is not the inverse matrix of H.

Comment: @MrWorshipMe that's correct. I'll modify when I'm able to. Thanks.